# To write a function in common lisp that will return the negation of a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I get this error with my current code:

```
 LET: illegal variable specification
   (COND (LISTP A (IF (NEGATE A) (NEGATE (REST L)) NIL))
    (T (SETF A (-A) (APPEND (LIST A) (REST L)) (NEGATE (REST L)) NIL)))
```

my current code:

```
(defun negate(L)
 (setq x -1)

 (if (not (null L))

  (let ((a (fitst L))
        (cond (listp a
              (if (negate a)
                  (negate (rest L))
                nil))
        (t
         (setf a (-a) (append (list a)(rest L))
               (negate (rest L))
               nil))))
)
))
```

and the test cases it needs to pass

```
o List is  (1 2 3 4)  
o Output should be: (-1 -2 -3 -4)

o List is  (1 -2 (3 4))  
o Output should be: (-1 2 (-3 -4) )
```

Comment: Hi, Your Cond test expression is missing one open parenthesis.
(cond (listp a ...   =>  (cond ((listp a ...

Answer (score 4):

In the most polite sense, your code is a bit off. You're learning Lisp this week, aren't you? That's OK! It's a fun language and can really do some awesome things.

So I'm going to walk through the creation of the routine, and take you along the tour.

Your basic case is -

```
(defun negate (n) 
  (if (> n 0) (- 0 n)))

(map #'negate '(1 2 3 4))
```

Walking the tree is more complex, but let's walk through the ideas.

Essentially, you have three cases to answer: is the current element nil, a list or an atom?

```
(if (not (car seq)) 
  (if (listp (car seq))
    ;;Recurse
    ;;Otherwise negate the current element and append it to the recursed.
```

Let's try a first cut at this:

```
(defun negate-seq (seq)
  (if (not seq)
      (return-from negate-seq))

  (if (listp (car seq))
      (negate-seq seq)
    (list (negate (car seq)) (negate-seq (cdr seq)))))
```

That's great! 
Except...

```
(negate-seq '(1 2)) ==> (-1 (-2 NIL))
```

And...

```
 (negate-seq '(1 (1 2 -3))) ==> STACK OVERFLOW!
```

Oh boy. We're in trouble now.

First, let's just try a `cons` instead of a `list`. 
That cleans up the weird nested list problem.

It's obvious that we're gotten into a loop of infinite recursion. That shouldn't be possible, because we've got the `not seq` guard. Okay, so let's try an debug. I'm using CLISP, and I can trace arguments with:

```
(trace 'negate-seq)
```

then,

```
(negate-seq '(1 (1 2 -3)))
```

Suddenly I see an explosion of

```
1621. Trace: (NEGATE-SEQ '((1 2 -3)))
1622. Trace: (NEGATE-SEQ '((1 2 -3)))
1623. Trace: (NEGATE-SEQ '((1 2 -3)))
1624. Trace: (NEGATE-SEQ '((1 2 -3)))
```

Crikey, I forgot my cdr and to cons up the list case! Hmmmm.

Let's try this:

```
(defun negate-seq (seq)
  (if (not seq)
      (return-from negate-seq))

  (if (listp (car seq))
      (cons (negate-seq (car seq))
        (negate-seq (cdr seq)))
    (cons (negate (car seq)) (negate-seq (cdr seq)))))
```

Recurse for the car, recuse on the car, cons them together, we might be on to something.

```
 (negate-seq '(1 (1 2 -3))) =>  (-1 (-1 -2 NIL)
```

Hmmmm. Let's take a look at the trace.

> 1. Trace: (NEGATE-SEQ '(1 (1 2 -3)))
> 2. Trace: (NEGATE-SEQ '((1 2 -3)))
> 3. Trace: (NEGATE-SEQ '(1 2 -3))
> 4. Trace: (NEGATE-SEQ '(2 -3))
> 5. Trace: (NEGATE-SEQ '(-3))
> 6. Trace: (NEGATE-SEQ 'NIL)
> 7. Trace: NEGATE-SEQ ==> NIL
> 8. Trace: NEGATE-SEQ ==> (NIL)
> 9. Trace: NEGATE-SEQ ==> (-2 NIL)
> 10. Trace: NEGATE-SEQ ==> (-1 -2 NIL)
> 11. Trace: (NEGATE-SEQ 'NIL)
> 12. Trace: NEGATE-SEQ ==> NIL
> 13. Trace: NEGATE-SEQ ==> ((-1 -2 NIL))
> 14. Trace: NEGATE-SEQ ==> (-1 (-1 -2 NIL))

So I recurse until the -3, then.... it falls off? Odd. Ah! I'm continually grabbing the CDR of things. A CDR is always a list. (cdr '(-3)) is nil!

Let's see here....

(much rummaging around)

Negate returns nil on positive. D'oh.

```
(defun negate (n) 
  (if ( > n 0) 
      (- 0 n)
    n))


(defun negate-seq (seq)
  "Written by Paul Nathan"
  (if (not seq)
      (return-from negate-seq))

  (if (listp (car seq))
      (cons (negate-seq (car seq))
        (negate-seq (cdr seq)))
    (cons (negate (car seq)) 
      (negate-seq (cdr seq)))))
```

Comment: a) `listp` returns `t` on `nil`, `consp` doesn't; b) use `cond` for `if/else`-s.

Comment: @hkachik: cond for if-else - *why*? The added complexity isn't worth it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you were looking for a gentle nudge to correct the code presented, or if you're soliciting other ways to do it. My first thought went to [`mapcar`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm#mapcar):

```
(defun negate-tree (tree)
  (mapcar (lambda (e)
            (cond 
              ((null e) nil)
              ((listp e) (negate-tree e))
              (t (- e))))
          tree))
```

You can then generalize out the negation aspect, and write `map-tree` instead, accepting a function to apply to the atoms in the tree:

```
(defun map-tree (f tree)
  (mapcar (lambda (e)
            (cond 
              ((null e) nil)
              ((listp e) (map-tree f e))
              (t (funcall f e))))
          tree))
```

You can call on it with, say, the unary negation function:

```
(map-tree #'- '(1 -2 (3 4)))
```

Such a call assumes that all the leaves in the tree are either `nil` accommodated by the unary negation function.

Accepting `nil` as a possible leaf in the tree makes the visitation algorithm a little messy, and it's not clear whether the provided function `f` should be applied to all leaves—even those that are `nil`—so that the function itself can decide whether and how to treat `nil`.

Another deficiency with this version is how it treats cons cells that are not [*proper lists*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_p.htm#proper_list). Note that function [`listp`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_listp.htm) returns true for all cons cells—even those that do not constitute proper lists—but `mapcar` does require that its input be a proper list. We can wind up along our "`listp` true" path, recursively calling on `mapcar`, and have `mapcar` fail for receiving an improper list. That means that the algorithm above either would need to test cons cells to see if they're proper lists before handing them to `mapcar`, perhaps treating those that aren't as leaves (I'm reluctant to say "atoms" here), or be documented that the expected tree structure is made up of proper lists of proper lists.

If you need to accept top-level "trees" that are not necessarily lists themselves, meaning that a lone atom is a valid tree, or `nil` is a valid tree, you can tear apart the constituent parts of the function above and write one that only uses `mapcar` after determining that the tree under inspection is a list.

Answer (score 3):

If you write:

```
 (defun negate (n)
   (if ( > n 0)
     (- 0 n)
     n))
```

then you're limiting your code to real numbers.

If instead you use the primitive negate function provided by Common Lisp, it will work on any number:

```
(mapcar (function -) '(1 2/3 #C(4 5)))     
--> (-1 -2/3 #C(-4 -5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do. Of course, I am considering only numberic lists. So, it would throw errors if the list isn't all numeric.

```
(defun negate (list)
      (flet ((negate-number (x)
           (- x)))
    (labels ((negate-helper (list neg-list)
           (if (null list)
               neg-list ; when all elements are considered return neg-list
               (let ((num-or-list (car list)))
             (if (numberp num-or-list)
                 ;; if number then negate it and add it into the new list (i.e. neg-list)
                 (negate-helper (cdr list) (append neg-list (list (negate-number num-or-list))))
                 ;; if list then first negate the sublist
                 (negate-helper (cdr list) (append neg-list (list (negate-helper num-or-list nil)))))))))
      (negate-helper list nil))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by the following procedure:

```
(defun negate (l)"returns a list of multiplication negative of elements of a list l,
                  element of list l to be each numbers for not to type err,
                  and list l may not be a list of atoms."
  (cond
   ((null l) nil)
   ((consp (car l)) (cons (negate (car l))
                          (negate (cdr l))))
   (t (cons (* -1 (car l))
            (negate (cdr l))))))
```

one can also have another version. i have tried to write a tail-recursive procedure, but it is not fully tr.

achieves same thing except it does not give the same order as original one. i can not now fix this:

```
(defun negate (l)
  (negate-aux l '()))

(defun negate-aux (l A)
  (cond
   ((null l) (reverse A));or A
   ((consp (car l)) (cons (negate (car l))
                          (negate-aux (cdr l) A)))
   (t (negate-aux (cdr l) (cons (* -1 (car l)) A)))))
```